# How to run shell script in systemverilog file

Tags: shell, system-verilog

I have this system verilog code. This verilog code need to run shell script and this shell script will run perl script. My compilation fail because it does not produce my output file which is output.sv. Below is my verilog code

```
module check_value( dut_if if );

   //Run shell script
   $system($sformatf("sh my_shell.sh"))

  //Output from the shell script   
   `include "output.sv";

endmodule
```

Also here, I provide my shell script. just incase, it needed.

```
 #!/usr/bin/tcsh -f

 unset PROJECT
 perl my_perl.pl
```

Comment: The $system command is evaluated at runtime, while the include is a preprocessor command, evaluated before compilation, so I don't see this ever working this way. Why can you not script/put in a makefile to first generate output.sv and then compile your module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$system` is a function that needs to be called inside a procedural block of code, like an `initial` block
2. That call gets executed at runtime, after compilation of all source code and processing of `` `include `` files
3. Your code will not compile until **output.sv** exists.

So you need to put your script execution outside your simulation script.

Comment: is there any way for me to update the output.sv file during the simulation? Let say I already run the script outside the simulation. Then, the input file in script is changes. How can I make when to run the simulation, the output.sv file will changes too,without re run the script?

Comment: You need to explain what you’re trying to accomplish, should be asked as a new question. What information is in your input file, and what kind of code does your script generate? I’m sure there are alternatives.